# Making a jQuery image slider stop at last image and adding next and prev buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following example which goes through each LI and if you hover image will pause and the continue when you mouseout but this is as far as I have got.

I would like it to stop when it gets to the last LI and also would like to make the 2 links I added wth classes "next" and "prev" so if clicked will move to next or prev image. Of course if at first image to set a class on prev like hidden and if on last image set next button to hidden so cannot be used, however this is as far as I have got.

```js
$( function() {
  var timer;
      lis = $(".productImage");
  
  function showNext() {    
    var active = lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active");
    var next = active.next();
    if (next.length===0) {
      next = lis.eq(0);  
    }
    next.addClass("active");    
  }
  
  function showPrev() {    
    var active = lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active");
    var prev = active.prev();
    if (prev.length===0) {
      prev = lis.eq(0);  
    }
    prev.addClass("active");    
  }

  function playGallery() {
    stopGallery();
    timer = window.setInterval(showNext, 2500);
  }

  function stopGallery() { 
    if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  
  // move to next image
  $('.galleryNext').on('click', function(event){
    stopGallery();
    showNext();
  });

  // move to previous image
  $('.galleryPrev').on('click', function(event){
    stopGallery();
    showPrev();
  });
  
  // reset slider timer if thumbnail changed
  $('.thumbnail-list li a').on('click', function(event){
    stopGallery();
    playGallery();
  });
  
  // pause image slider if mouse is hovering gallery main image
  $(".featured-image-list")
    .on("mouseleave", playGallery)
    .on("mouseenter", stopGallery);

  playGallery();
  
});
```

```css
.productImage {
    display : none;  
}

.productImage.active {
    display: block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="featured-image-list">
  <li class="productImage active">1</li>
  <li class="productImage">2</li>
  <li class="productImage">3</li>
  <li class="productImage">4</li>
  <li class="productImage">5</li>
</ul>
<a class="galleryPrev">prev</a>
<a class="galleryNext">next</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modifying your code a bare minimum I've come up with this:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/Lpgbzy2w/)**

Simply placing showNext() and showPrev() within the functions below gets the next and prev buttons working with the caveat that it also stops the slides from auto progressing (and I see in your edit that's what you did):

```
function nextImage() {
  stopGallery();
  showNext();
}

function prevImage() {
  stopGallery();
  showPrev();
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to come up with a solution to that.

And you can also edit your showNext and showPrev functions with the addition of the following:

```
// add to showNext()
if (next.next().length===0) {
    stopGallery();
    nextBtn.addClass("hidden");
}

// add to showPrev()
if (prev.prev().length===0) {
    prevBtn.addClass("hidden"); 
}
```

Comment: I clcked next and disabled right away, guess should be when on 1st prev disabled and click next goes until last and that disables... and prev enables when it hits second? thanks for helping but think not working right :(

Comment: Almost, anyway to default disable the prev link? i updated button position here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpgbzy2w/4/

Comment: I maybe had prev and next buttons backwards? Have a look at the jsfiddle again. Works for me :)

Comment: To default disable the prev link I would simply add the "hidden" class in the html